# How to express a quantity?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-choice, numbers, quantifiers

I want to form a sentence in which I say that *'Puzzle is divided into pieces'*, and in the same sentence I want to say that the number of pieces is equal to *'N'*. How can I say it correctly and shortly?

> *Puzzle is divided into pieces, in a number of N*
>
> *Puzzle is divided into a number of pieces, equal to the number N*
>
> *Puzzle is divided into pieces, equal to the number N*
>
> *Puzzle is divided into pieces, the number of pieces is equal to the number N*
>
> *Puzzle is divided into pieces, their number is equal to the number N*

Actually these are wild guesses, what is the best way?

Note: I don't want to say *"Puzzle is divided into N pieces"*

Comment: If N = 500, _This is a 500-piece puzzle_.

Comment: Good point - is the puzzle already divided i.e. is this a jigsaw puzzle, or are we about to divide it?

Comment: Why don't you want to say "The puzzle is divided into N pieces."? This is the most natural phrasing.

Answer (score 4):

The best answer is the one you don't want :-) You could say:

> The puzzle is divided into a number of pieces, which we will call *N*

Although grammatically this sounds as though we are calling the pieces N, the meaning will be clear. You could also say:

> The puzzle is divided into pieces, the number of which we will call
>   *N*

Comment: I don't want to call it number N, the number N is known

Comment: Then the question has to be asked: why don't you want to say "The puzzle is divided to 5 pieces?" (or 2, or 387, or 14,216)

Comment: OK - just seen the other comment - the puzzle is already divided; you are not doing the dividing. Then "This is a N piece puzzle" is  probably the best way.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to say "The puzzle is divided into N pieces," (a perfectly good option), you can say:

> The puzzle has 8 pieces. (Good)
>
> It is an 8 piece puzzle. (Good)
>
> The puzzle is divided into pieces, numbering N. (awkward, but understandable)
>
> The puzzle is divided into pieces, equaling number N. (more awkward)

The rest are even worse. Putting the number of pieces into a separate phrase makes you come across like a bad math textbook that is deliberately trying to confuse students by wording questions poorly.

Comment: how about *"The puzzle is divided into pieces whose number is equal to N."* ?

Comment: A reader will be able to figure out what you mean, but it's awkward and roundabout. Why are you trying so hard to avoid saying "divided into N pieces?" If we knew why, we might be able to help with better suggestions.

Comment: because `N` actually stands for a number of something else, so it could be replaced by e.g. *"whose number is equal to the number of fingers"* or something like that. So I can't say *"divided into number of fingers pieces"*